# Get Count of Items in WPF Toolkit AutoCompleteBox Dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf, autocompletebox

Is there a way to get the count of the items currently showing in the dropdown in a WPF toolkit autocompletebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `Populated` event:

```
private void AutoCompleteBox_Populated(object sender, PopulatedEventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in e.Data)
        count++;

    string text = count + " items shown!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could even just do this and avoid the loop:

```
private void AutoCompleteBox_Populated(object sender, PopulatedEventArgs e)
{
   int count = ((ReadOnlyCollection<object>)e.Data).Count;
}
```